# Open a PDF located in a local network with a WebView Android

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am trying to open a PDF in a WebView. The problem is that the PDF is located on a server in the local network. Should I first download the PDF to the device and then try and open if from there, or is there a workaround which would not involve me downloading the PDF to the device?

Comment: `The problem is that the PDF is located on a server`. No. The problem is that a WebView does not display .pdf's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to save the PDF on the sd card in the device form the server. Once I did this I was able to launch a PDF viewer from my application.